# How to vectorize a time series data in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vector

Im doing a monte carlo simulation of stock prices and im trying to reduce the computational time of my code. How will I vectorize this?

```
# t  = number of prices to be simulated
# N  = # of simulations
# S0 = starting price
Z_S = np.random.normal(0,1,(t,N))
St  = np.zeros((t,N)
St[0,:] = S0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(1,t):
        St[j,i] =  St[j-1,i] + r*St[j-1,i]*dt + np.sqrt(v0*dt)*St[j-1,i]*Z_S[j,i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is time series, only one layer of vectorisation is possible here.

```
for j in range(1, t):
    St2[j, :] = St[j-1,:] + r*St[j-1,:]*dt + np.sqrt(v0*dt)*St[j-1,:]*Z_S[j,:]
```

Needs to be done.

However, you can use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to JIT this and it might still be as fast as any vectorised code. It internally vectorises your code even when you have a bunch of loops by compiling it at run-time. Whenever you need to vectorise time series data, I recommend that you use this.